# Manjaro desktop background script

Tags: manjaro

I recently installed Manjaro i3 edition and I'm loving life so far. Specifically, the Arch wiki is just the greatest thing ever. Everything is easily configurable as long as you know what to look for. In this instance, however, I don't. Look at the following screenshot:

[image]

To be frank, this frantic obsession the Linux community seems to have with keeping the CPU load stats under constant surveillance will probably remain a mystery to me until the day I die. But I digress.

The text here (the blue one) is dynamically generated, probably from the stdout of some bash script somehwere. What I want to know is which one(s)?

Comment: If I have to guess I'd say [conky](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/conky). Try `killall conky`. I think it's autostarted from your `.i3/config`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct it seems, thank you!

Comment: @resc, seems enough for an Answer, if you like!